# Could not access file: 2020-09-25 08:56:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

My debug output:

```
2020-09-25 08:56:12 Could not access file:
2020-09-25 08:56:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO eugenev.fun
2020-09-25 08:56:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2020-09-25 08:56:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: ZXVnZW5lLnZlcHJ5dHNreWlAZ21haWwuY29t
2020-09-25 08:56:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: OXNEU3Fha3Jsd0JuMlRWdg==
2020-09-25 08:56:12 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed:
    534-5.7.14
    534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 
    534-5.7.14 Learn more at
    534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 p22sm1857696lji.100 - gsmtp
2020-09-25 08:56:12 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2020-09-25 08:56:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-09-25 08:56:12 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Error
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please edit your question include the shortest amount of code  needed to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue, so problem is ...
I needed to unlock some Captcha, to get access from new device, now all working.

https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: This is a very common problem that's documented via **both** the links that appear in the debug output, in particular [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps).